# Macbook Pro Late 2011 stuck at 0.8 GHz

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, performance

I have been experiencing a lot of problems with my Macbook Pro slowing down and crawling through small tasks like getting mail and opening Launchpad. I have 8 GB of 1333 MHz DDR3 memory and a 2.2 GHz Quad-Core i7, so this seems very odd. I downloaded the Intel® Power Gadget before upgrading to Mavericks and it was showing 1.0 GHz for my CPU, even while playing Diablo 3 and running Netflix. I booted up into the Mavericks GM seed and it easily moved up to 3.4 GHz with the same apps running. I figured that upgrading to Mavericks on my main partition would solve this, but I am now stuck at 0.8 GHz.

What could possibly be causing it to stay at 0.8 GHz, and how do I fix it? I can barely get my Macbook to do anything at this speed.

Comment: Try logging in as a different user on your main partition. Does it still register .8MHz?

Comment: @MarkThalman It hangs around 1.4 GHz when it is not under load, so it seems to be just fine on that user.

Comment: Then it is probably a corrupt preference file or some other problem on the first user. I'd start by repairing disk permissions in disk utility. Rereading my first comment, my Apple //e ran at 1MHz :).

Comment: @MarkThalman That worked for a few minutes, but now it is back down to 0.8 GHz. It seems that was just a symptom of a bigger problem.